# Changing fontawesome icon on click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a 'volume' icon that will mute sounds when clicked, and unmute when clicked again. I used .addClass() and .removeClass() to toggle between icon classes. While I am able to change from "fa-volume-up" to "fa-volume-off", I cannot do the reverse; for some reason it's not passing the "else if" condition after the icon has changed to 'volume-off'.

I want to change the icon from 'fa-volume-up' to 'fa-volume-off'.

```js
// index.js
$(function() {
  $('#vol-btn').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('fa-volume-up')) {
      $(this).removeClass('fa-volume-up').addClass('fa-volume-off');
      //sound.mute(true);
      console.log("Muting sound.")

      // it won't enter this condition!
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('fa-volume-off')) {
      $(this).removeClass('fa-volume-off').addClass('fa-volume-up');
      //sound.mute(false);
      console.log("Unmuting sound.")
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--index.html -->
<div class='btns'>
  <i id='vol-btn' class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: wouldn't `toggleClass` make more sense in this situation

Comment: it's working as expected .. there must be some issue with your `sound.mute` function

Comment: Maybe it's too small. `i {display:block;padding:8px;cursor:pointer}` add class `.fa-2x`

Comment: https://codepen.io/codespent/pen/KeOKbG working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Derek that toggling the icon makes more sense - then using the class to determine the console.log message (which I am doing in a ternary operator).

```js
// index.js
$(function() {
  $('#vol-btn').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('fa-volume-up fa-volume-off')
    $(this).hasClass('fa-volume-off')
      ? console.log('Muting sound')
      : console.log('Unmuting Sound')
  })
})
```

```css
#vol-btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--index.html -->
<div class='btns'>
  <i id='vol-btn' class="fa fa-volume-up fa-2x"></i>
</div>
```